# UITextField: How to react to the "Done" key and validate the input

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am attempting to regulate some login/sign up requirements for my application, so when a user selects the "Done" button on the keyboard, i want to send an alert depending on if there was an error with their inputed text. Sort of like instagram does:

[image]

I am trying to prevent the the uses of the any characters outside of regular letters and numbers in inputed strings, so I'll knock out two birds with one stone with this question:

1) How do i access the "Done" button programmatically to right code , and what method should i use to detect the uses of any characters outside of letters and numbers in a textfield's string? I know how to present the alert view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Reacting to "Done" Taps

You need to implement the `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate method. Inside of it you can check the text field's text against your set of forbidden characters and only dismiss the keyboard when all characters are valid.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let forbiddenChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "@(){}[]")
    for c in textField.text.utf16 {
        if forbiddenChars.characterIsMember(c) {
            println("found forbidden character")
            return false
        }
    }
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

## Handling Multiple Text Fields

If you have more than one text field, you need to set the `tag` property on each of your text fields and then act on its value in the delegate method. Here is an example for choosing a different set of invalid characters based on the text field's tag.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let forbiddenChars: NSCharacterSet
    if textField.tag == 0 { // e.g. password field
        forbiddenChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "@(){}[]")
    } else { // tag != 0, e.g. user name field
        forbiddenChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "*?.<>\\")
    }
    ...
}
```

In a real world application you should of course define constants for the tags instead of using literal values.

## Using a White List for Character Validation

If you want to use a white list of allowed characters rather than a black list, you just need to flip the conditional.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let allowedChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefg...")
    for c in textField.text.utf16 {
        if !allowedChars.characterIsMember(c) {
            println("found forbidden character")
            return false
        }
    }
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

## Denying Input of Invalid Characters Completely

If you want to deny the input of invalid characters altogether, you need to implement the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method and strip any unwanted characters from the replacement string.

```
var myTextField: UITextField

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if count(string) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    let forbiddenChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "@(){}[]")
    var correctedReplacement = ""
    for c in string.utf16 {
        if !forbiddenChars.characterIsMember(c) {
            correctedReplacement += "\(UnicodeScalar(c))"
        }
    }

    if count(correctedReplacement) > 0 {
        myTextField.text = (myTextField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: correctedReplacement)
    }

    return false
}
```

## Limiting the Length of the Input

Unfortunately, the `UITextField` class offers no built-in way to set a maximum length for the entered text. If you want to work around this, you need to implement the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method and drop characters from the replacement string as soon as the desired maximum length is reached.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if count(string) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    let maxLength = 10
    var trimmedReplacement = ""
    for c in string {
        if count(textField.text) - range.length + count(trimmedReplacement) >= maxLength {
            break
        }
        trimmedReplacement += "\(c)"
    }

    if count(trimmedReplacement) > 0 {
        myTextField.text = (myTextField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: trimmedReplacement)
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what if i want to regulate the length of a string? i figured i just ask since its on the same topic

Comment: @MikeStrong This kind of starts to go beyond the scope of the original question. :) Anyways, you need to check the length of the resulting string in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` and trim it to a substring of the desired length if it's too long.